# What is triggering "triggerScroll" event?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

When I click a button to change some states within my nuxt app, i'm being scrolled down the page.

With the vue extension I can see the following event:

```
name:"triggerScroll"
type:"$emit"
source:"<Root>"
```

What could cause this event to be triggered? I'm not triggering it within my code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [the scrollToTop property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-scrolltotop/) or `this.$refs.module.scrollTop = 0`, `$nuxt` will fire a `triggerScroll` event